# What is the minimum ios deployment target for swift 5?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using swift 5 and Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001). Need to update my [pod](https://github.com/NikKovIos/NKVPhonePicker) to swift 5. What is the minimum ios deployment target for this? `s.ios.deployment_target`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set any valid iOS version between `8.0` to `12.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Minimum deployment for Swift 5 is iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I thought You've set Deplyment Target upto **12.1**

- [Check Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2)